# Reveal a plaintext with 3 encryptions of Textbook RSA

Tags: rsa

Assume we using Textbook RSA encryption with the public key $(N,3)$.
How can I learn message $m$ if I have the encryptions of $m,m+1,m+2$ in an efficient way?

I'm studying for a test and it's a question from one of the tests of the past

Comment: Hint: express the three (known) ciphertexts as a function of $m$ and known quantities. then solve for $m\bmod N$.

Comment: I got:
C1 = m^3 mod N,
 C2 = (m+1)^3 mod N,
 C3 = (m+2)^3 mod N

 - But I do not see how to proceed from here...

Comment: Expand, then eliminate terms in $m^3$ and $m^2$ by Gaussian elimination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
m^3 & & & \pmod n\\
(m+1)^3 &= m^{3} + 3 \, m^{2} + 3 \, m + 1 & & \pmod n\\
(m+2)^3 &= m^{3} + 6 \, m^{2} + 12 \, m + 8 & &\pmod n\\
\end{align}

Now multiply $(m+1)^3$ with $\color{red}{2}$

\begin{align}
m^3 & & &\pmod n\\
\color{red}{2}(m+1)^3 &= 2m^{3} + 6 \, m^{2} + 6 \, m + 2 & &\pmod n\\
(m+2)^3 &= m^{3} + 6 \, m^{2} + 12 \, m + 8 & & \pmod n\\
\end{align}

Now substruct first and third equation from the second

\begin{align}
2(m+1)^3 - (m+2)^3 - m^3&= - 6 \, m -6 \pmod n\\
2 \cdot c_2 - c_3 - c_1 &= - 6 \, m -6 \pmod n
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I was between delete and undelete. I hope this is not HW.

Comment: No it's not homework, it's just an exercise as part of preparing for a test I could not solve.

Comment: In Math, it is always good to expand the given as much as possible you can to see some relations around.

Comment: Also, next time show your work, that is better for you.